# Deny access to one of two sites using the same .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, apache, multiple-domains, block

I need to set up my `.htaccess` file to deny access to the site if they are accessing the `staging.example.com`.

I have a Magento 2 store and have set up deployment using Capistrano, which will be deploying to 2 separate domains: `staging.example.com` and `example.com`. They will have the same `.htaccess` file and I want to allow access to the staging site by IP only.

Currently using Cpanel and you don't have access to the vhost files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can use something like this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?subdomain\.com$ [NC]
> RewriteCond ${ipmap:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} !^(127\.0\.0\.1|192\.168\.|10\.|1\.2\.3\.4)$
> RewriteRule ^ - [F]
> ```

Source: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28437130/) from [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) on Stack Overflow

You can also allow specific IP addresses and deny the rest with this:

```
order deny,allow
allow from 31.24.232.14
allow from 127.0.0.0
allow from 192.168.0.0
deny from all
```

These might also help:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'www.example.com'">
Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</If>
```

---

There's a good chance this last one is what you want. If the code works, it will detect that the website loaded is not `example.com` (but your subdomain). And if it's your subdomain it will block all IP addresses except the one that you list in the allow from.

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'www.example.com'">
    order deny,allow
    allow from 31.24.232.14
    allow from 127.0.0.0
    allow from 192.168.0.0
    deny from all
</If>
```

You could also try:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} = 'subdomain.example.com'">
    order deny,allow
    allow from 31.24.232.14
    allow from 127.0.0.0
    allow from 192.168.0.0
    deny from all
</If>
```

#### For Apache 2.4+

If you're going to use `require ip`, you may need to do it like this:

```
Require all denied
Require ip 123.123.123.123
```

Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865658/htaccess-allow-deny-ip-using-require-apache-2-4

Maybe this works?:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} = 'staging.example.com'">
Require all denied
Require ip 123.123.123.123
</if>
```

Sources are also showing that you need `RequireAny` to allow only specific IPs. If that's the case you may have to modify it for your subdomain requirement condition:

```
<RequireAny>
Require ip 1.2.3.4
Require ip 23.34.45.56
</RequireAny>
```

Comment: The last one might work, but I'm trying to stay away from that. Since it's being depreciated. "The Allow, Deny, and Orderdirectives, provided by mod_access_compat, are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use."

Comment: Oh wow that's good to know. I use some allow, deny so I'm glad you told me so that my sites don't break if they deprecate this.

Comment: Updated my answer for apache 2.4+

Comment: But I want this rules to only apply to the subdomain staging.example.com

Comment: "`${ipmap:%{REMOTE_ADDR}}`" - This should be simply `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` (in the `RewriteCond` directive at the top) - `ipmap` refers to a rewrite map, which hasn't been defined here.